# Salesforce Marketing Cloud Contacts without a channel

Tags: marketing-cloud

In our instance of Salesforce marketing cloud, I queried the ContactKey/All Contacts without a channel (no Email or no Mobile) in Contact Builder and there are approximately 90K records that have no emails or mobile numbers yet they are counting as contacts. Basically there are no channel associations for these contacts when I look at the attributes for the contacts - Is there a way to find out where these contacts came from. We do have the connect enabled in which Salesforce Contacts, Leads and Users are being synced in Marketing cloud with email being a must and present in all - so I don't believe there is an issue with the connection. I just want to know if there is way to know when and how a ContactKey/contact was generated for contacts without any channels.

Comment: subscribers are added to all contacts from sync objects even if you haven't sent to them, they only get added to a channel once you have sent them a message or import them in that channel

Comment: Thank you - Yes I'm aware of that and I've accounted for those in my analysis - I'm seeing  approx. 90K contacts that don't exist in in of the sync objects from Saleforce CRM.

Comment: If you delete a subscriber in SFDC it will remove them from the sync object but does NOT delete them in SFMC

Comment: thanks again - Yes I'm aware of that as well - the contacts I'm referring to in SFMC do not have any channels associated with them  - The SFDC connection only brings in contacts, leads and users with an email address or mobile number - so I'm not sure why some ContactKeys in SFMC are generated without a channel.

Comment: just becuase your contact has an email/mobile in SFDC doesn't mean they are added to a channel, you must send to them to be added to a channel

Comment: Thanks EazyE - I'm aware of that as well - the records I'm referring to do not exist on any of the sync data sets; Contacts, leads or Users - but they do exist as a contact in contact builder. My question is how do I track back a contact for me to see how and where they came from?